# How can I animate a sequence of 10 Images in iPhone OS?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

I have 10 small images that have to be shown quickly one after another in order to make an animation effect. Is there an easy way to do that, or must I implement an routine by myself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Really easy. The UIImageView has built in support for such animations. It has two important properties: animationImages and animationDuration. I would recommend you to check the docs.

Answer (score 1):

[cocos2d-iphone](http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/) can do this easily. It might be overkill for your project, but it is pretty easy to work with.

Comment: I think that is taking the problem an overcomplicating it by a very large factor. The UIImageView class has support for animating sequences of images as described by another answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

This should be easy enough to do using [Core Animation](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html).